# Any reason why I am getting extra spacing underneath.. IE6-7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Any reason why I am getting extra spacing underneath each input on my contact form?

It only happens in ie6 and ie7

http://nhbs.bythepixel.com/contact.html

Comment: @Roeland, I updated my answer and added a sample page for you to test. It should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tested.** Just use this code for IE in conditional stylesheet if u are using

```
FORM#contactform .input { margin-bottom: -11px; }
```

**or** put in head directly like this code

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 FORM#contactform .input { margin-bottom: -11px; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

It's a IE bug you can see more details here:

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/inherited_margin.html

http://forums.devshed.com/css-help-116/margin-bug-in-ie7-a-kind-of-the-double-margin-548527.html

Answer (score 3):

probably newlines... ie tries to print "whitechars" between tags

Answer (score 1):

IE sometimes treats whitespace (text nodes) as occupying space among floated elements.  Don't freak out when I suggest this, but have you considered putting the `input` elements in a `table`?  Yes, table-based layouts are horrible, except in this case your content is actually arranged in a table, so it would be perfectly appropriate.

Comment: freakin out right now....!!! aahhh.  hehe jk, to be honest i would like to avoid using tables. if anything I would rather stick it in an unordered list.. but thats so much extra un-needed code.. just like a table structure would be ya know?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your page (or move the style to an IE only stylesheet) and it *will* fix your problem:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  #contactform { height: 1% }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

[**Working example here**](http://pixelgraphics.us/test/nhbs.html) (View in IE6 or IE7)

Comment: no it's not a solution , it's not a IE double margin bug it's different. IE double margin bug is only for Horizontal margin not vertical

Comment: @Jitendra, good point! I changed it to `height: 1%` and it took care of the issue.